# Legend doesn't appear in ggplot with two different geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my data shown as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)      

Year_2012_2017 <- data.frame(a=c(5,4,2,5,4,6,6,12,7,7,6,3),
                  b=c(6,4,1,2,9,7,4,7,8,12,2,4),
                  c=c(1,1,6,4,5,7,11,14,10,6,7,8),
                  d=c(4,9,5,3,4,11,9,11,10,8,4,9),
                  e=c(4,4,5,3,1,19,10,11,19,8,7,9),
                  f=c(4,5,3,6,5,12,25,15,21,24,14,1))
Year_2012_2017$mean <- rowMeans(Year_2012_2017)
Year_2012_2017<- transform(Year_2012_2017, Min = pmin(a,b,c,d,e,f), Max = pmax(a,b,c,d,e,f), seq = seq_len(dim(Year_2012_2017)[1]))

Year_2018 <- data.frame(g=c(10,5,7,6,9,26,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
Year_2018 <- data.frame(Year_2018,seq1 = seq_len(dim(Year_2018)[1]))

Month_name <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

And my graph code:

```
ggplot(Year_2012_2017) + 
geom_line(aes(factor(seq), mean), group = 1,size=1, color = brewer.pal(7, "Set1")[2],lty=2)+ 
    #Mean of 2012 to 2017

geom_ribbon(aes(x = seq, ymax = Max, ymin = Min, fill= "Min-Max(2012-2017)"),alpha = 0.5)+ 
scale_fill_manual("",values="skyblue")+                                                                   
    #Min and max

geom_line(aes(Year_2018$seq1,Year_2018$g),group = 1,size=1, color = brewer.pal(7, "Set1")[2],lty=1)+ 
    #Year of 2018

coord_fixed(ratio=1/6)+
xlab("Month") +
ylab("Number of case")+
scale_x_discrete(labels=Month_name)+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30),breaks=seq(0,30,5))
```

Which produces the following graph:

[two lines and one ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqLD2.png)

I tried for quite a while but **failed to add legend of two geom_line()**, can anyone help me find the solution? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See the duplicate question - the trick is to rearrange your data so it's all in one dataset and you can do `aes(..., colour = year)`. The other answer where you just do `aes(..., colour = "2018")` will also work but it's not making full use of ggplot's automatic aesthetic mapping magic.

Comment: Thanks but actually I checked the duplication before. My case is a bit more complitated than previous questions. As I tried before, rearranging as combining the data is hard to implement, while "scale_color_manual" fails to work.

Comment: Some data is tricky to rearrange to the preferred  ggplot format, but I just checked and the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391502/1222578 does work for your data. Make sure you are putting a label into `aes()`, e.g., `geom_line(aes(factor(seq), mean, color = "2017"), group = 1, size=1,lty=2)`.

Comment: I've tried the second answer and made 100% sure "color" was in "aes()", it did't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for reference, but it is a direct application of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391502/1222578). If you can't rearrange your data so that it's all in one dataframe with common columns, a workaround is to
put labels in `aes()` and you will get a legend:

```
ggplot(Year_2012_2017) + 
    geom_line(aes(factor(seq), mean, colour = "2012-2017"), group = 1,size=1, lty=2)+ 
    #Mean of 2012 to 2017
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = seq, ymax = Max, ymin = Min, fill= "Min-Max(2012-2017)"),alpha = 0.5)+ 
    scale_fill_manual("",values="skyblue")+                                                                   
    #Min and max
    geom_line(aes(Year_2018$seq1,Year_2018$g, colour = "2018"),group = 1,size=1, lty=1)+ 
    #Year of 2018
    coord_fixed(ratio=1/6)+
    xlab("Month") +
    ylab("Number of case")+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=Month_name)+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30),breaks=seq(0,30,5))
```

Comment: Did you really try your answer in R and did it work? I told you I’ve already tried but the legend just doesn’t show as I expected. Something must be wrong

Comment: @Lan, yes, the answer I have posted here is tested against the example code and data you gave. So I correctly recognised that an existing question had an answer that worked for you, tried to explain that to you multiple times, and then when you were unable to adapt the answer yourself, did your work for you and showed you how to do it